# Graphite add-ons

Tags: monitoring

Where can I find add-ons for the [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/) graphing tool, to monitor server memory usage, disk/network activity and other common metrics?

Answer (score 2):

Be careful graphite doesn't collect any data, it displays data that some other process send to it.

Check http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tools.html for a list of tools that are graphite friendly, I use collectd+collectd-carbon[1] it works very well

[1] https://github.com/indygreg/collectd-carbon

Comment: Carbon uses Whisper, which in turn only allows "average" for the reduction function when promoting to older buckets.